# Php json treeview from phpmyadmin database

Tags: php, mysql, json, treeview

I want to get json treeview with php from phpmyadmin database. When I click on a product, only fields for that product will open.

```
table `category`
id  product             parent_id
1   cars                0
2   commercial vehicle  1
3   maruti              2
4   bmw                 2
5   tata                2
6   bike                0
7   motorcycle          6
8   bajaj               7
9   hero                7
```

Output will be in three horizontal parts like this:

```
cars    >>  commercial vehicle  >>  maruti
                                >>  bmw
                                >>  tata
```

Like when I click on bike, it will open like:

```
bike    >>  motorcycle  >>  bajaj
                        >>  hero
```

I am using this code but fails to achieve the output.

```
<?php
$return_arr = array();

$fetch = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM category"); 

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($fetch, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    $row_array['id'] = $row['id'];
    $row_array['product'] = $row['product'];
    $row_array['parent_id'] = $row['parent_id'];
    $row_array['children'] = 
    $row_array['level'] = 

    array_push($return_arr,$row_array);
}

echo json_encode($return_arr);
?>
```

For children and level how to write the code? Results come here without `children` and `level`` like..

```
{"id":"1","product":"cars","parent_id":"0"}...
```

Plz suggest how to get

```
"children":["3","4","5"] and "level":2 field where {"id":"2","product":"Commercial Vehicles","parent_id":"1"}
```

or

```
 "children":["8","9"] and "level":2 field where {"id":"7","product":"motorcycle","parent_id":"6"}
```